# How to get the checkbox value using Django

Tags: django, checkboxlist

i am new to Django ,I want to get the Checkbox values , I am using the getlist() method for getting the values iit gets the value but if i passthe value to the data retriving code it shows some "Type Error " i don't understand why this error is Shown ...Code is Below

```
Views.py

def edit_estimate_def(request):
context_csrf = RequestContext(request)
value = request.POST.getlist('inputs')
create_estt = create_est.objects.filter(id = value)
#----- Here only I got The Error, the above line it shows Type Error
       int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'


context = {'create_estt': create_estt}
if request.method == 'POST':
    introductory_paragraph = request.POST.get('introductory_paragraph')
    editable_signture_area = request.POST.get('editable_signature_area')
    statement_of_needs = request.POST.get('statement_of_needs')
    inline_checkboxes = request.POST.get('inline_checkboxes')
    weeks  = request.POST.get('weeks')
    payment_terms = request.POST.get('payment_terms')
    create_est.objects.filter
    (project_title =value).
    update(introductory_paragraph=introductory_paragraph,
    editable_signture_area=editable_signture_area, statement_of_need$
return render_to_response('accounts/edit_estimate.html', context,context_csrf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `value` is a `list` object you have to use `__in`:

```
create_estt = create_est.objects.filter(id__in=value)
```

[Link to the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept my answer if it was useful for you, thanks :)